# How to run message to MQ server and get output message back

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, ibm-mq

I want to send a message to MQ server and receive the output message back. For example, the message is "pwd", the message I received back should be the directory path such as "/usr/home". However, my receiveMessage returns exactly same message I sent "pwd". Is there a way that my receiveMessage can return the directory patch?

```
connectionFactory.setCCDTURL(ccdt.tab);
connectionFactory_.setQueueManager(QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME);
MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection)connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
connection.start();
MQQueue mqQueue= new MQQueue();
MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(mqQueue);
JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage)session.createTextMessage("pwd");
message.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId);
sender.send(message);
MQQueueSession session =(MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
String selector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + correlationId + "'";
MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(mqQueue, selector);
TextMessage receiveMessage = (TextMessage) receiver.receive(500);
receiver.close();
System.out.println("Received Message: " + receiveMessage );
```

Thanks

Comment: MQ is not going to run unix commands for you.  You would need an application that read the message received, ran a command, and then sent a reply message back with the response.

Comment: oh! I see! thanks i didnt know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided is simply putting a message with the text `pwd` to a queue and then getting the same message back from the queue. The result you see is what would be expected.

If you wanted to be able to send a message to a queue where the content of that message would be executed and the output of that command returned to you, you would need to write a program to perform that function.